# nw in powershell; themes ignored

Tags: microsoft-windows, themes, terminal-emacs

I'd like to run emacs in powershell (on windows 7) with `emacs -nw` with the misterioso theme.

When I `M-x load-theme` `misterioso` the theme'ing doesn't happen.  However when I `M-x load-theme` `manoj-dark`, I get pretty colors.

Is there something I can do to fix powershell to play nicely (or fiddle with misterioso)?

Comment: `manoj-dark` doesn't seem to have any classes with minimal number of colors supported, but `misterioso` does for the foreground and background. You technically could try to make a small edit to it to set a foreground and a background regardless of the number of supported colors, but I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  In the end I found color-themes to be much more consistent within powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in themes are old 'n busted (at least in windows 7 powershell).  Use [color-themes](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorThemes) instead.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as a solution to the problem.